# Oracle APEX framework is too slow responding to pages requests

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle18c, oracle-apex-18.2, oracle-apex-20.1

Edited: Any page takes long time to open, starting from the sign in page along with app builder, any custom app, object browser, sql commands, etc... .
I am using `APEX 20.1, ords-20.2.0.178.1804, DB 18c XE , windows 7 64bits, Google chrome Version 84.0.4147.125 (Official Build) (64-bit) and opera Version:70.0.3728.106.`
The problem occurred too when I used `12c release 1 enterprise edition with apex 18.2 and ords 18.4.`
Here is a video to show you what I mean and the details follow,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7fz31jimCuA
When I am using it, Task Manager shows that I have about 700 Free memory space.
Here is a system summary

```
OS Name Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate  
Version 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601  
Other OS Description Not Available  
OS Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation  
System Name A-PC  
System Manufacturer Dell Inc.  
System Model Latitude E6410  
System Type x64-based PC  
Processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 560  @ 2.67GHz, 2667 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)  
BIOS Version/Date Dell Inc. A17, 12/05/2017  
SMBIOS Version 2.6  
Windows Directory C:\Windows  
System Directory C:\Windows\system32  
Boot Device \Device\HarddiskVolume1  
Locale Egypt  
Hardware Abstraction Layer Version = "6.1.7601.17514"  
User Name a-PC\a  
Time Zone Egypt Standard Time  
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 4.00 GB  
Total Physical Memory 3.80 GB  
Available Physical Memory 1.87 GB  
Total Virtual Memory 7.60 GB  
Available Virtual Memory 5.29 GB  
Page File Space 3.80 GB  
Page File D:\pagefile.sys
```

The database has one pluggable database(the default one).
Automatic Memory Management is enabled with MEMORY_TARGET set to 1100, SGA_TARGET and PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET set to 0.

The only thing I can notice in Task Manager> Performance Tab> Resource Monitor window is that there are number of hard faults/sec associated with processes `oracle.exe`, `searchindexer.exe` and one `chrome.exe` process. But the maximum number I've seen was 13 and rarely displayed. The majority were 1,2,3, etc... . And they're not always seen. I do not think it could cause this bad performance.
What could be the cause? How do I investigate it?

Comment: Too slow at doing what? It's highly unlikely anyone here is going to spend their time watching your video. Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then update your question.

Comment: "a slow running application" is a term used in Oracle documentation. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/htmdb/identifying-performance-issues.html#GUID-9F64557B-855B-4F0E-8034-147FA5D31B90
The video is only 38 seconds. I thought if a pic is worth a thousand word, a video would worth a million. Any way I edited the title of the question and the main post. I hope it's more clearer now. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

One big issue that I can see is the amount of RAM in your system being 4GB. With Memory_target=1100  + OS + Chrome + Database no wonder you have performance issues.
Basically you need more memory to run all those components..

I invite you to use https://apex.oracle.com in that environment you have the right resources to ensure consistent and proper response time.

Comment: At the end, I still have memory available to be used. Then where is the problem?! I managed to have more than one GB free memory after disabling some windows services that I don't need. And the problem is still there!

Comment: Now I have 6GM of RAM and still have the same issue!